# how to check if string contain words batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, substring

i want to create simple program to check if output of command contain error stop the next command.

here what i try

```
@ECHO OFF

SET list=fatal
SET list=%list%;error 
SET list=%list%;conflict 
SET list=%list%;failed

git pull origin master > temp.txt

for %%cWord in (%list%) do (

    SET /P vPull=<temp.txt

    IF NOT x%vPull:%%cWord=%==x%vPull%
    ECHO please fix the error then try to pull again!

)

PAUSE > nul
```

code above to execute the `git pull origin master` and then check if the output of command contain `list` string or not, if yes program will stop to execute the next command.

i try the code above but the program exit when i open.

Comment: Could you show me the results in `temp.txt`?

Comment: @GerhardBarnard look like it store nothing, i got empty text..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you want something like this:

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=1,2*delims=:" %%i in ('git pull origin master 2^>^&1') do (
    set rtncode=%%i:%%j
    if /i "%%i"=="fatal" echo %%i:%%j & goto :end
    if /i "%%i"=="error" echo %%i:%%j & goto :end
    if /i "%%i"=="conflict" echo %%i:%%j & goto :end
    if /i "%%i"=="failed" echo %%i:%%j & goto :end
)
echo %rtncode%
echo When you get here, you did not experience the errors above, so code can go here
:end
Pause
```

To explain the code. `for /f` uses delimiter `:` to split the string into two parts, everything before the `:` is then assigned to the fist metavariable `%%i` and everything after `:` is assigned to `%%j` because we specifically said that we want to use tokens `1` and `2`.

The important part here is the `2>^&1` bit after the command. This specifies thatr we should redirect the stderror to stdout. This allows the error messages to be assigned to the metavariables as well as the normal success messages. We then just match each of the assigned metavariables `%%i` with the hardcoded text `fatal`, `error` etc. so the match will end up being something like this. The metavariable `%%i` has the value assigned to it, let's say `fatal`:

```
 if /i "fatal"=="fatal"
```

The above matches, so it will then execute the condition

```
echo %%i:%%j & goto :end
```

Which will print the stored error message and exit the loop and bypass any commands before `:end`

you can open `cmd.exe` and run the following for more help:

```
for /?
if /?
```

I added `set`ting `%rtncode%` which will assign any output to it, which will be shown if you do not match any of the errors in the loop.

Comment: i got nothing. when i open, cmd pop up, after a while it close..
example output error is like this `fatal: Couldn't find remote ref master`. this messages can be multiple lines..

Comment: I added pause. Copy and try again

Comment: What is the name of your batch file?

Comment: `gitproccess.bat`

Comment: Sorry, I actually did `goto :eof` which skipped the `pause` I have updated it now, please try the code again as is.

Comment: look like its work, but can u please explain the code?

Comment: Yes. I will update the answer with some explanations in a while.

Comment: ok, wait for it, and can you make little modify.. i still want to show the result of command whatever it error or not..

Comment: Explanation added and amended code to cater for the success messages as well.

Answer (score 0):

I may have misunderstood your question, but it seems like this untested single line is all that's needed:

```bat
@git pull origin master 2>&1 1>CON|Find /V ""&&(Echo Ending script. Please fix the error then retry.&Pause>NUL&GoTo :EOF)||Pause
```